Unity XR View mesh
I have done several steps to get the current mesh. That mesh is used by SMPLX model, and I set the shape parameters from a json that is calculated from a pose using a camera.
Right now I would like to view the red spheres, or at least mark them in an XR scene.
The current mesh the pose is estimate and the bones are deformed based on that.
How would I or the process the mesh or the sphere points so that they face the human on a bed for example, and those red spheres reflect on his body ?

